# Hibernate doesn't appear to save data on close

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I'm attempting to restore a HSQL database with a series of SQL insert statements using Hibernate.  No errors are thrown, and after it cycles through all of the statements the data appears to be in the database.  The problem is after I close application and start it back up, the data is missing.  I can query it from the session right up until I close it, though.  Here is what I'm doing:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession
try {
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    if (insertStatement != null && !insertStatement.isEmpty()) {
        Query q = session.createSQLQuery(insertStatement);
        q.executeUpdate();
    }
    transaction.commit();
    session.flush();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It doesn't seem very complicated and it does seem to work, at least until I've closed my connection to the database.  I have checked to see what HSQL database it's connecting to during restore and first I first load the application and it's the same.  What am I missing that's preventing this from persisting?

Comment: are you sure you do not run in-memory db only?

Comment: Nope, definitely persisting it to a file.  Opening up the application and saving data works just fine, nothing lost.  The only problem I seem to have is persisting these INSERT statements.

Comment: It might be worth noting that I've only opened one session.  The actual try block is looped through, committing and flushing every statement.  After all of the INSERT statements have been executed, then I close the session.

Comment: Please post you connection parameters,  i.e. your jdbc URL.

Comment: Sure: jdbc:hsqldb:file:*FilePathToDB*\rtDB;crypt_type=blowfish;check_props=true;hsqldb.lock_file=false;shutdown=true;crypt_lobs=true;hsqldb.applog=0;hsqldb.sqllog=0;hsqldb.log_data=false;crypt_key=*bootkey*

That's what I use to connect to it, to create it "create=true" is just appended to the end.  Saving objects such as session.saveOrUpdate(user) works just fine.  It's only native SQL statements that's giving me problems.

Comment: Check if `executeUpdate` returns 1, and remove all non essential parameters from your URL. Check the log_data file and be certain to close the session prior to close the db.

Answer (score 0):

You have added the `hsqldb.log_data=false` to prevent data changes from being logged.

With this setting, you must execute the SHUTDOWN command explicitly in order to persist the data. There is no alternative when you disable data change logging.